# Storing data temporary then simulating-iOS

Tags: ios, json

Imagine that you are reading json data from the server continuously. let's say, you are getting weather data. I want to show only data 2 hours back from now. Whenever user clicks on the play button, it would show weather data on the map.
How I could save json data first then show it on the map. Because that would enhance my application instead of connecting server , getting data and showing it at the same time. please just give me advice. Do I need to save it first as a plist or an array? Where should I keep this data before I simulate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've many options to store your data in `iOS`.

1. SQLite Database
2. PList File
3. `NSUserDefaults`
4. Core Data
5. As a file in `NSDocumentDirectory`
6. GenericKeychain - To store sensitive data. ([Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html))

Choose the best, that you know & do well. Say, managing data with `SQLite` is little tough as you've to make connection and queries for the data insert, update, selection etc. `Plist file` & `NSUserDefaults` can be easy if you've little size of data using `key/value`combination. You can also store data in a file if its not structured data in `NSDocumentDirectory`, there's one more Core Data, as I've no idea about it, but you will find good example if you google it.

So its all depends on size and type of data you've to manipulate. It's all depends on how frequently you'll going to use it (like selection, updating or even insert new data).